# Applying impulse at angle based on touch location

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm currently developing a game with a cannon that shoots a projectile, I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the projectile to fire at the angle based on the touch location and how far away it is from the cannon. this is the code i'm using below.

```
let dx = cannon.position.x - (touchLocation.x)
        let dy = cannon.position.y - (touchLocation.y)
        let angle = atan2(dy, dx)

        bullet.zRotation = angle
        bulletspeed = Double.random(in: 1...6)

        //let angle1 = Double.random(in: 0.2...5); let angle2 = Double.random(in: 1...4)

        // dx must be somewhere between 0.2 to 5
        bullet.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -angle , dy: -angle))
```

this doesn't seem to work and i've resorted to using the angle as my x and y values which works but not well.

I'm trying to get the cannon to fire based on the angle of the touch location and to change the speed/power of the projectile by how far way the touch location is from the cannon. **How can I do this?**

Comment: You don’t need an angle. You need a vector which takes dx and dy. in your first two lines of code you are calculating dx and dy. why not use those?

Comment: Also, when you say it doesn’t seem to work. Can you explain what that means? What is it doing?

Comment: @Fogmeister when I use the dx and dy it fires, but the projectile goes too fast and i can't see it (so i'm guessing my vector is too much) and only when i press at certain part of the screen i manage to see it fly off the screen. when i use the angle it works better than using dx and dy but its not the right way or even close to how i want it.

Comment: ah, ok, let me write an answer.

Comment: You need to subtract the cannon's position from the touch location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector you need to use takes in dx and dy as parameters. You already have these but you say the speed is too fast. That’s because the length of the vector is the speed.

So in your example the speed can be calculated like...

```
sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
```

What you need to do is calculate a ‘unit vector’ that is, a vector with length equal to one.

You can do this by dividing dx and dy by the length of the vector.

So...

```
touchDX = //your calculation
touchDY = //your calculation

touchLength = sqrt(touchDX*touchDX+touchDY*touchDY)

unitVectorDX = touchDX / touchLength
unitVectorDY = touchDY / touchLength

// now put the speed you want in...

speed = 10

vector = CGVector(dx: unitVectorDX * speed, dy: unitVectorDY * speed)
```

Now, if you use the vector in your impulse it will have the correct direction and speed.

Quick side note, I’m typing on my iPad so don’t have access to code completion etc... you may be able to do this using APIs on CGVector. I think I remember a ‘unitVector’ property that returns a unit vector. But I may be mistaken.

Comment: Its works, but it doesn't always get the angle right, meaning that sometimes when i fire the projectile it sometimes flys past above where i've tapped on the screen or way below it if i tap a little further down on the screen. is this because of the speed not changing with the location of the touch and being static all the time?

Comment: yeah it didn't help but i've developed my game past the point of needing it to fly at the click location perfectly so its all good. thanks for your answer. i appreciate it!